# On React Component Using array.filter() and not recieving a return value, (if no matching elements it should be an empty array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am running the following function component with React.
I am destructuring a name parameter using useParams, and I want to use it to specify the array of dog objects being passed in and destructered as props.

Using console.log I can see that the dogs array is passing into the component with no trouble, and using array.map() can confirm it is an array. name is also destructured and being passed in via useParams and confirmed with console.log
The issue I am having is that array.filter(dogs.filter) is returning no response.
There is a matching object and property in dogs, which its contents I have included below.
So I cannot seem to see when I print out my copy variable that I have no data.
Any ideas, Im sure its something simple I just cannot seem to grasp it.

```
const Home = ({dogs}) => {
    //all dogs. 

    //lets destructure name from our useParams hook. 
    const {name} = useParams()
    console.log(name)
    dogs.map(m => console.log("mapping: " + m)) // it is an array
  
    let queryDog;
    if(name){
        console.log("name is truthy")
        let copy = dogs.filter(d => d.name === name)
        console.log("here is a copy: " + copy)
        queryDog = copy
    }else { queryDog = dogs
    }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {queryDog.map(d => 
        
       <Dog name={d.name} age={d.age} src={d.src} facts={d.facts} key={uuidv4()}/>

      )}

    </div>
  )
}
```

Here are the dogs, an array of objects passed into the Home component.

```
App.defaultProps = {
  dogs: [
    {
      name: "Whiskey",
      age: 5,
      src: "whiskey.jpg",
      facts: [
        "Whiskey loves eating popcorn.",
        "Whiskey is a terrible guard dog.",
        "Whiskey wants to cuddle with you!"
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Duke",
      age: 3,
      src: "duke.jpg",
      facts: [
        "Duke believes that ball is life.",
        "Duke likes snow.",
        "Duke enjoys pawing other dogs."
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Perry",
      age: 4,
      src: "perry.jpg",
      facts: [
        "Perry loves all humans.",
        "Perry demolishes all snacks.",
        "Perry hates the rain."
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Tubby",
      age: 4,
      src: "tubby.jpg",
      facts: [
        "Tubby is really stupid.",
        "Tubby does not like walks.",
        "Angelina used to hate Tubby, but claims not to anymore."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

tried to troubleshoot and understand the nature of the issue.

Comment: What does your query look like? Can you output the "name" coming from the params? Are you actually sending a parameter with "name"? 

Either the parameter your sending doesn't match the name of the objects, or the data you are passing in as `{dogs}` is not the right data, or is structured differently than you are expecting (for example, there is no d.name property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only calculating the filtered array once before the component even renders, therefor name might be null, or dogs might be null. What you want to do is set up a side effect. Every time your dog array or name value changes, we need to re-filter the list right?

At bare minimum there needs to be a useState and useEffect.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
const Home = ({dogs}) => {
    //all dogs. 

    //lets destructure name from our useParams hook. 
    const {name} = useParams()
    console.log(name)
    dogs.map(m => console.log("mapping: " + m)) // it is an array
  
    const [queryDog, setQueryDog] = useState(dogs);

    useEffect(()=> {
         // This is a callback function that executes anytime the value of a dependency changes which need to be passed inside the array in second param. Every time those values change this function will execute
    if(name){
        const copyArray = dogs.filter(dog => dog.name === name);
        setQueryDog(copyArray);
    } else {
        setQueryDog(dogs) // reset to original array
    }
    }, [name, dogs]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {queryDog.map(d => 
        
       <Dog name={d.name} age={d.age} src={d.src} facts={d.facts} key={uuidv4()}/>

      )}

    </div>
  )
}
```

This will achieve the effect you desire. However this scenario is ideal for React.useMemo. Please look into the documentation for more information.

```
const Home = ({dogs}) => {
    //all dogs. 

    //lets destructure name from our useParams hook. 
    const {name} = useParams()
    console.log(name)
    dogs.map(m => console.log("mapping: " + m)) // it is an array
  
  const queryDog = React.useMemo(() => (name ? dogs.filter(dog => dog.name === name) : dogs), [dogs, name]); // any time these values change this function executes and stores the value for queryDog in memory.

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {queryDog.map(d => 
        
       <Dog name={d.name} age={d.age} src={d.src} facts={d.facts} key={uuidv4()}/>

      )}

    </div>
  )
}
```